# Error fusedLocationApi requestLocationUpdates() non-activity class error

Tags: android, location, updates, locationlistener, fusedlocationproviderapi

Hi I'm new in stackoverflow. I hope someone Know how to do something in Android to call method requestLocationUpdates using FusedLocationApi.

I'm trying to call in a non-activity class that implements the classes nedded to request location updates: 
        **LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);**

But it shows message that "Cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates(...)"

```
 /**
 * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
 */
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

And the non-activity class that I use implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener and LocationListener and extends my activity class.

```
public class OnMapGps extends OnActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    ...
    ...
}
```

The error that shows is:

```
Error:(306, 42) error: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,OnMapGps)
method FusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,LocationListener)
is not applecable (argument mismatch; OnMapGps cannot be converted to LocationListener)
```

Comment: It seems you're about to have more problems, given that you say you're extending your Activity class  in a "non-activity" class.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, it seems that i had the wrong import LocationListener. I had

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

And the correct is

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

I think that I had to ask to find the solution myself. :P

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by casting 'this' into a 'LocationListener' Object

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Solution**]

import below

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

Add the below permission to the manifest file, This is required. After that issues will be resolved.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Code

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
```